# surefire test output missing

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project where all tests are green when I run it at home, and a test times out when ran on shippable. I went to great efforts to make sure that the build environment is the same: it runs in the same docker container with exactly the same scripts, and most of the environment variables are also the same.

There is one other difference besides the failing test: the output of System.out.println() is seen in the tests ran at home, and does not seen in the tests ran at shippable.

How do I make sure that standard output/error from tests ends up on the console?

Here is a failing run for reference: https://app.shippable.com/github/edemo/PDEngine/runs/958/1/console